# Installing papi on virtualbox(use counters on virtual machine )

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, papi

I'm using ubuntu with virtualbox on windows 10. I'm having problem to use any function of the papi library and getting (Error in PAPI_flops: Event does not exist) error. 
When I run the make test of the installation guide, I have this:

[image: error list]

But the perf command is working perfectly.
What do i need to do to activate counters on virtual box.
And if that is not my problem, then what is?
thanks ^^.